# Read nested json in php

Tags: php, json

I know others have already asked about this, but I don't find a solution for my problem. In my PHP page I call an external service and I can't modify the response obtained.

I'm moving my first steps both with JSON and PHP.
The response is a JSON like this, I print this using the `var_dump` method:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3)
{
    ["search_string"]=>string(15) "ABCDEFG HI LMNO"
    ["resut"]=>string(5) "apixi"
    ["0"]=>array(1){
       [0]=>object(stdClass)#2(2){
          ["resp_code"]=>string(7) "12.34.0"
          ["resp_description"]=>string(15) "ABCDEFG HI LMNO"
       }
    }
}
```

In my PHP page I can read the value ”ABCDEFG HI LMNO” for the key "search_string" with this code, in the `$output` variable I store the result of the cUrl call

```
.......
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$jsonDecode =json_decode(str_replace('""','"',$output));
var_dump($jsonDecode);
echo $jsonDecode -> search_string;
```

I need the `str_replace` method because the JSON is dirty but not always, how can I access at the fields "resp_code" and "resp_description" and then store them in a variable? I tried many solutions but none works for me.

Comment: can you show sample of json that you are getting as a response.

Answer (score 0):

In the decoded JSON you have, the *resp_code* and *resp_description* keys are difficult to get to, because the top-level object has a numerical ("0") attribute. Trying to reach that attribute like this:

```
$jsonDecode -> 0
```

will give this parsing error:

> syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Trying the same with a string notation (`-> "0"`) also fails.

However, the suggestion in the error message is useful: *encapsulate the zero with braces.* Then you can proceed easily by adding the array index selector (`[0]`) to get to the object and keys of your interest, like this:

```
echo $jsonDecode->{0}[0]->resp_code;
echo $jsonDecode->{0}[0]->resp_description;
```

If you expect more elements in that array `$jsonDecode->{0}`, then loop over them like this:

```
foreach ($jsonDecode->{0} as $element) {
    echo $element->resp_code;
    echo $element->resp_description;
}
```

#### Alternative

If, however, you prefer to work with associative arrays instead of objects, you can use the second argument of [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as stated in the docs:

> **assoc**
>
> When **TRUE**, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So then you would pass **true** as second argument:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode(str_replace('""', '"', $output), true);
```

The above code would then be rewritten like this to access the variable as an associative array:

```
foreach ($jsonDecode[0] as $element) {
    echo $element["resp_code"];
    echo $element["resp_description"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting JSON array to `stdClass` object you can also convert it to regular PHP array by adding second parameter to the `json_decode` function:

```
$jsonDecode =json_decode(str_replace('""','"',$output), true);
```

In your case in the output, you'll get a multidimensional array.

Then, to access `resp_code` and `resp_description`, you can do something like this:

```
$respCode = $jsonDecode[0]["resp_code"];
$respDescription = $jsonDecode[0]["resp_description"];
```